# How can I use >= correctly? Is (a+f()+c)>=0 wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int he = 1;
vector<vector<int>> matrix { { 1, 5, 9 }, { 10, 11, 13 }, { 12, 13, 15 } };
bool bo=(he - matrix.size() + 1) >= 0;
```

I think `bo` is false, but it is true.
I do not know why. Is it wrong for an lvalue?

Comment: `bo` should be false, as (1 - 3 + 1) is -1, which is < 0. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Your matrix size is bigger than 2 so the calculation expression is certainly less than 0. So the bool expression is false as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by: I think bo is false,but it is false. I do not now why? It seems like you think it is false and that's exactly what it is so what's you question here???

Comment: bool bo=(he - matrix.size() + 1) >= 0, I see the result,bo is true. I do not know why.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `>=` has lower precedence than the arithmetic operators. In practice that means that you don't need those parentheses. `bool bo = he - matrix.size() + 1 >= 0`; says the same thing as the version with (redundant) parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

`matrix.size()` is an unsigned type, so the entire expression is promoted to unsigned. The comparison is `unsigned(1 - 3U + 1) >= 0`, or `unsigned(-3) >= 0` which is always true. (`unsigned(-3)` will be something like `0xFFFFFFFD` for 32 bit integers.)

You can cast it to the expected type

```
bool bo = int(he - matrix.size() + 1) >= 0;
```

although this might generate a compiler warning if `size` returns a larger type (`unsigned long`) than `int` (change the type used in the cast if this is the case).

Comment: Imo normalizing types as early as possible is the most useful pattern to avoid relying on implicit conversion rules. So, I’d prefer doing a `static_cast<int>(matrix.size())` instead. Actually, I have my doubts about the exact conversion rules for an `int - unsigned long + int` expression, so removing those doubts at the earliest possible point seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

`matrix.size()` has type `size_t` which is unsigned.
Thus `he - matrix.size() + 1`, which should have the value
`-1` on an arithmetic point of view has actually a very
high positive value (due to wrapping below zero).
That is why the comparison shows an unexpected result here.